# DigitalOcean - Ubuntu php8.1 - pecl install grpc g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus - ERROR: `make' failed

Tags: grpc, digital-ocean, pecl, php-8.1

Can't get pecl to install grpc.

**Command**

```
sudo pecl install grpc
```

**Error**

```
g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:226: src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/client_channel.lo] Error 1
ERROR: `make' failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change/Resize your Droplets RAM to 4gb and try re-installing should work now. I was on a 1GB droplet.

Worked for me and took me days to find a fix/workaround for this.

Hope it help someone else out there.